# Reading rules from xml in Drools 6.3

Tags: java, xml, drools

I'm trying to read rules from XML using drools 6.3. I've tried to find some examples, but I found nothing of value, just one example of converting xml to drl which doesn't work because I'm using newer version of drools...

I converted drl example generated by eclipse to xml and replaced it by this xml. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package name="com.sample" xmlns="http://drools.org/drools-5.2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://drools.org/drools-5.2 drools.org/drools-5.2.xsd">
    <import name="com.sample.DroolsTest.Message"/>
    <rule name="Hello World">
        <lhs>
            <pattern identifier="m" object-type="Message">
                <expr>
                    status == Message.HELLO
                </expr>
                <expr>
                    myMessage : message
                </expr>
            </pattern>
        </lhs>
        <rhs>
            System.out.println( myMessage );
            m.setMessage( &quot;Goodbye cruel world&quot; );
            m.setStatus( Message.GOODBYE );
            update( m );
        </rhs>
    </rule>
    <rule name="GoodBye">
        <lhs>
            <pattern object-type="Message">
                <expr>
                    status == Message.GOODBYE
                </expr>
                <expr>
                    myMessage : message
                </expr>
            </pattern>
        </lhs>
        <rhs>
            System.out.println( myMessage );
        </rhs>
    </rule>
</package>
```

Right now drl is loaded like this:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
```

But this doesn't load xml files.

Is there any example how to load xml? Do I have to convert it to drl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The development of an XML version for DRL has been officially terminated several versions ago, around 5.2, IIRC. DRL has developed into a quite sophisticated language, and keeping its XML counterpart up-to-date has turned out to be a considerable but unrewarded effort.

Also, a conversion to the vendor-independent Rule-ML (for a subset of) DRL isn't something a vendor pursues eagerly, for obvious reasons.

It is not evident from your question why you are interested in rule authoring in XML. More help might be forthcoming if you add something of the background of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for insight. I want to generate rules based on user input in custom GUI and then send rules to server where data will be evaluated based on these rules. I thought that xml would be easier to generate than drl. Now I am trying to do it using "Fluent" API (not sure of this name), so creating rules right in java, which will create drl for me. So far its working, however I haven't found many examples of its usage, so I am afraid of some obstacles in future.

Comment: This is the right choice. The "fluent" API - although not part of the "stable" API - should be comprehensive enough and accurate for your intended purpose.